# Is there a way to pass unicode symbols in the PAM conv function?

Tags: c, linux, ssh, pam

I am creating a PAM module to show a QR code to users that are trying to log onto a system over SSH to allow them to scan it and authenticate using biometrics on their phone. Is there a way to pass unicode characters into the PAM conv function to allow the application to display them to the user?

The reason I need to hand in unicode characters is because I want to use the uincode character █ (`U+2588 Full Block`) as a way to print the QR code to the screen.

I have tried using the type `wchar_t` to hand in the value and also just trying to hand it in as char but both end up printing the missing character question mark to the screen.

If this is not possible is there a way of being able to show a QR code prior to authentication at all or is regular text the only possible thing to show?

Pam conv struct from PAM source:

```
struct pam_conv { 
    int (*conv)(int num_msg, const struct pam_message **msg,
        struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr);
    void *appdata_ptr;
};
```

Edit (31/10/21): I have tried the suggestion of encoding as UTF8 which I beleive is done like so: `\u[unicode char code]`. This produced the following compiler warning:

```
src/pam-qr.c:118:58: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  118 |             row[x] = qrcodegen_getModule(qrcode, x, y) ? '\u2588' : ' ';
```

and this output:

```
\210\210\210\210\210\210\210 \210  \210\210\210 \210\210 \210\210\210\210\210\210\210\214\2723O\177
\210     \210      \210  \210 \210     \210\214\2723O\177
\210 \210\210\210 \210  \210\210 \210  \210\210 \210 \210\210\210 \210\214\2723O\177
\210 \210\210\210 \210 \210    \210 \210\210 \210 \210\210\210 \210\214\2723O\177
\210 \210\210\210 \210 \210\210    \210\210\210 \210 \210\210\210 \210\214\2723O\177
\210     \210 \210         \210     \210\214\2723O\177
\210\210\210\210\210\210\210 \210 \210 \210 \210 \210 \210\210\210\210\210\210\210\214\2723O\177
        \210\210\210    \210\210        \214\2723O\177
\210   \210 \210\210\210\210  \210 \210\210 \210\210\210\210\210  \210\214\2723O\177
 \210     \210 \210\210 \210 \210\210\210  \210\210    \214\2723O\177
\210\210\210  \210\210    \210\210\210\210\210 \210 \210 \210\210\210 \214\2723O\177
 \210\210\210\210\210  \210  \210\210    \210    \210\210 \214\2723O\177
  \210\210  \210\210\210  \210\210 \210 \210\210\210\210 \210\210\210\210\214\272
```

The following is the output I get when using `#` instead of the block character:

```
####### #  ### ## #######
#     #      #  # #     #
# ### #  ## #  ## # ### #
# ### # #    # ## # ### #
# ### # ##    ### # ### #
#     # #         #     #
####### # # # # # #######
        ###    ##        
#   # ####  # ## #####  #
 #     # ## # ###  ##    
###  ##    ##### # # ### 
 #####  #  ##    #    ## 
  ##  ###  ## # #### ####
#  ##  # #    #### ### # 
   #  ## ##  ### # ##    
  #### # ## #  #  #   #  
###  ## ## # ## ##### #  
        ### # # #   ### #
####### # ##### # # #    
#     #   ## #  #   # #  
# ### # # # ##  #########
# ### #  #   ### ##    ##
# ### #  ##      ### # # 
#     #     # ##  ### ## 
####### ## # ### # #  ###
```

This can't be scanned but the printed version with the block character can be hence why I want to use it. This is the desired output using the block character that I'm trying to achieve:

```
███████ █  ███ ██ ███████ 
█     █      █  █ █     █ 
█ ███ █  ██ █  ██ █ ███ █ 
█ ███ █ █    █ ██ █ ███ █ 
█ ███ █ ██    ███ █ ███ █ 
█     █ █         █     █ 
███████ █ █ █ █ █ ███████ 
        ███    ██         
█   █ ████  █ ██ █████  █ 
 █     █ ██ █ ███  ██     
███  ██    █████ █ █ ███  
 █████  █  ██    █    ██  
  ██  ███  ██ █ ████ ████ 
█  ██  █ █    ████ ███ █  
   █  ██ ██  ███ █ ██     
  ████ █ ██ █  █  █   █   
███  ██ ██ █ ██ █████ █   
        ███ █ █ █   ███ █ 
███████ █ █████ █ █ █     
█     █   ██ █  █   █ █   
█ ███ █ █ █ ██  █████████ 
█ ███ █  █   ███ ██    ██ 
█ ███ █  ██      ███ █ █  
█     █     █ ██  ███ ██  
███████ ██ █ ███ █ █  ███
```

Comment: It is possible to pass absolutely anything. `void *` doesn't care. You probably want to ask "how can I print Unicode characters from my function?", and show your current attempt.

Comment: So am I able to cast anything to void * and hand it into the conv function shown above without getting erros? Also would the app that is using the passed in value not have difficulties as it is expecting something of type char *?

Comment: `'\u2588'` won't work. This Unicode character is not representable as a single `char`. UTF-8 is a *multibyte* encoding. You need to read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), now. Or rather 10 years ago.

Comment: You also assume that the remote terminal is geared to display this character, which is a brave assumption.

Comment: In that case would you say it's impossible to display a QR through the pam conv function when logging in?

Comment: It is *in general* not possible. It could be possible if the remote terminal is set up to render Unicode characters in a specific encoding, but a PAM module cannot check that. Assuming the terminal can render UTF-8, your module needs to print UTF-8. If you can(not) do that from a toy "hello world" program, then you probably can(not) do that from a PAM module, so I'd suggest starting with a toy program. Can you display a *single* Unicode character with 10 lines of C code or less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I wasn't actually putting in the ASCII block character to the conv function but rather I was putting in code to change the colour of the terminal. This ended up being printed as is during auth hence why the QR code didn't show up.

Fixed it now by sending in the proper ASCII block character which when treated as a string prints perfectly well to the user during PAM auth.

Answer (score 1):

You can try encoding your Unicode data as UTF-8.  That's the most commonly used encoding on Linux, and many programs justifiably refuse to support anything else.  Unless you need to emit U+0000, you can use a standard C string to store all your Unicode code points in UTF-8.

However, if your goal is to print the QR code on a terminal, you may end up with problems, since terminal characters are usually not square and there is no standard proportion for them.  Thus, it's possible that your QR code won't render acceptably on the terminal and that it will be difficult or impossible to read for the phone.  There are programs that do this, so presumably it works in at least some cases, although it may not work everywhere.  You may find that `libqrencode` is useful in your endeavours.

Comment: I tried using libqrencode to do the encoding of the QR code but couldn't get it working. I am using a different library for encoding now. I don't think libqrencode has anyway of returning the qr code as a printable string?